# How to set a picture/wallpaper as folder's background

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How can I set desired wallpaper in folder's background(not a thumbnail view) in windows 7 without any special software? I want to put a picture instead of white background of a folder.(I know this feature was in windows 2000. I don't exactly remember, but I think it was made in folder properties, and then "Desktop.ini" file was created in that folder).

Comment: what do you mean by the folder's background? you mean this tiny image that shows up when you're looking at a folder? or do you mean [THIS](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-54Kbo64xpIs/UgzRAC--ldI/AAAAAAAAA4Q/zFMlqzZ33PE/s320/Folder-Background-Windows.png)

Comment: No, not a thumbnail view. When opening a folder it has a white background. It was possible in windows 2000 to change that "white" to a picture. I don't know exactly about windows XP or later.

Comment: I dont understand, why are you asking about 2000 when your question tags say windows 7. Can you please re-write your question and BE MORE SPECIFIC on what you want.

Comment: @Sickest: he wants to change the Windows Explorer background. i.e. the white space. He's saying that was possible in Windows 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Create a new folder (to an existing folder) and then right-click choose properties, then customize, then change the icon to the 2nd one from top left (the folder icon)
when you open folder you wont find anything but it contains a file desktop.ini to make it visible

Step 2. Go to Tools -> Folder options -> click on view then here make sure that u

a) Click on show hidden icons

b) Hide extension for known file type option is not marked (not selected)

c) Hide protected operating system files option is not marked (not selected)
the options b and c are just below the show hidden icons option

Click ok and then open the folder u just created (plus changed the icon)
you will find a file name desktop.ini (which was hidden earlier)
open that file and paste this part of code :

```
[{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC...
iconarea_image=C:\WINDOWS\Web\Wallpape...
iconarea_text=0x00ffffff
```

Now the file must look something like this

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32...
IconIndex=4

[{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC...
iconarea_image=C:\WINDOWS\Web\Wallpape...
iconarea_text=0x00ffffff
```

The code in red `C:\WINDOWS\Web\Wallpaper\Crystal.jpg` indicated the location of the image used as background, in this case image crystal.jpg is located in c->windows ->wallpaper so change this to the image location u want as background and its done save you file.

You can even change the code in green it indicates the icon names color, which you can change according to your choice -- `0x00ffffff` indicated white, `5x55555` indicates black etc. (you can use html color codes after `0x` six digit color code). That's it, if you are having trouble then just watch the video at top.

One more thing after everything is done go to my computer -> tools -> folder options -> view -> click on do not show hidden icon and click (select) the two options below it.

1) Hide extension for known file type option

2) Hide protected operating system files option)

[source](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090728175957AAqXYQe)

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried to create desktop.ini file and put a code like that in it. But it's not working. May be I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, this is what i found, try the steps again or google search it a bit more, i know there are 3rd party pieces of software that do this as well. But I can't see too many people actually attempting to do this, so it's not really worth the effort to try it myself. good luck.